VPN connection intrusion
I've been doing a regual thing such as connect to my own VPN service and accessing my own private resources but noticed a strange thing.
After connection succeeded (client: Windows 10, IKEv2, server: StrongSwan) the web browsing and RDP had a large response time.
I've browsed to ip check website to check if the VPN actually got connected. I've tried three similar sites and all of them showed a strange IP6 address. These address was not my VPN server address (I use IP4 address on it) and it was not an address of my ISP because the ISP address resolves to some town that is near the capital city. But the address was from the middle of capilal.
I've rechecked VPN status in Windows tray and it was "connected".
It lasted several minutes, then my IP address started to resolve as my VPN server address.
Our country is experimenting with blocking foreign resources and VPNs as well.
So I've got a question is it possible that my VPN connection was intercepted and accepted by some DPI (or other) system and then switched to the original VPN server?
If yes, what was visible to the DPI (or other) system in my traffic?
Can it be done because I've installed (automatically, but from verifyed services) many trusted certificates in Windows certificates store (such as from government institutions and legal companies that provide services for signing documents with digital signature)?
I use StrongSwan with LetsEncrypt sertificates for my domain.
